# QR factorization and eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I really can't find an answer to this. I am writing a C code to solve the eigenvalues problem for a real symmetric matrix A. The procedure is the following.

I have a real symmetric matrix A. I put it in tridiagonalized form, P being the matrix that tridiagonalizes A. Then I write the QR factorization of the tridiagonal matrix and I find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the final (upper) triangular matrix thus obtained. Up to now everything is fine.
But from this point, how can I relate these eigenvalues and eigenvectors to those of the original matrix A?

I read of the QR algorithm but I am looking for a more direct approach. I solved the eigensystem of the triangular matrix yet and I am looking for a relation (involving matrices P and Q) that gives the same for the matrix A. How can I proceed?

Comment: The QR *algorithm* for eigenvalues uses the QR *factorization* repeatedly in an iterative fashion, along with other operations. You don't just do the QR factorization once. This is a common misconception caused by bad naming. For more details, see here: https://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter4.pdf

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Per the discussion in the comments, I misunderstood the question. The intention of the question is to know whether it is possible to easily recover the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$ if we know the QR decomposition of $A$, and we know the eigenvalue decomposition of $R$.

Basically, the answer is no, it is not possible to recover the eigenvalues of $A$ from this information using any finite algebraic process. To see why, note that general-purpose eigenvalue algorithms always require an infinite iterative process. This is because the solutions of a polynomial equation are the eigenvalues of [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) for the polynomial, and by the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) there is no algebraic solution of 5th order polynomials in general.

But here everything is (in principle) a finite algebraic process:

1. Taking a QR factorization of $A$,
2. Getting the eigenvalues, $\lambda_R$ of $R$ by looking at its diagonal.
3. Finding the eigenvectors of $R$, by finding vectors in the null space of $A - \lambda_R I$

If one could use $Q$ and the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $R$ in an algebraic process to get the eigenvalues of $A$, this would imply that the eigenvalues of $A$ are algebraic in the entries of $A$, which would imply the existence of algebraic solutions to any polynomial, which would contradict the Abel-Ruffini theorem.

---

**Old answer:**

The [QR algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) for eigenvalues uses the [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) repeatedly in an iterative fashion. At each step you compute the QR decomposition of the current matrix, then multiply the factors in reverse order to get the next matrix.
\begin{align}
&A_1 = A \\
Q_1 R_1 = A_1, \quad &A_2 = R_1 Q_1 \\
Q_2 R_2 = A_2, \quad &A_3 = R_2 Q_2 \\
Q_3 R_3 = A_3, \quad &A_4 = R_3 Q_3 \\
\dots
\end{align}
Eventually this process will converge to a triangular matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal.
You don't just do the QR decomposition one time. This is a common misconception caused by bad naming. For more details, see here:

> "Lecture Notes on Solving Large Scale Eigenvalue Problems." Peter
> Arbenz. Chapter 4.
> https://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter4.pdf

Here is an example in python/numpy where I do the QR algorithm for 20 iterations on a 4x4 symmetric matrix:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randn(4,4)
A = A + A.T
print('Initial A:')
print(A)
true_eigs, _ = np.linalg.eigh(A)
for k in range(20):
    Q, R = np.linalg.qr(A)
    A = R @ Q

print('Final A:')
print(A)
qr_eigs = A.diagonal()
print('true_eigs=', true_eigs)
print('qr_eigs=', qr_eigs)
```

This outputs the following:

```
Initial A:
[[ 3.69583037  0.57095943  1.25982728 -0.91138766]
 [ 0.57095943 -5.72767862  1.40997728  3.09590731]
 [ 1.25982728  1.40997728  0.84352098 -0.00810195]
 [-0.91138766  3.09590731 -0.00810195  2.71813063]]
Final A:
[[-7.00604910e+00  3.73685766e-02 -1.74171532e-05  3.95274785e-16]
 [ 3.73685766e-02  4.60446175e+00 -3.51557676e-03 -6.65769624e-17]
 [-1.74171532e-05 -3.51557676e-03  3.57531666e+00  4.29698141e-16]
 [-9.44786542e-25 -2.34167099e-22  1.01641538e-19  3.56074064e-01]]
true_eigs= [-7.00616937  0.35607406  3.57530465  4.60459402]
qr_eigs= [-7.0060491   4.60446175  3.57531666  0.35607406]
```

Comment: I know this, but i don't want to use the QR algorithm. In my case I have the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of R_1 and i want to determine those of A_1. Are you telling me that the QR algorithm is the only way to do this?

Comment: @D.Alfano I don't think this is possible. Eigenvalue computations always require an infinite iterative process. This is because the solutions of a polynomial equation are the eigenvalues of companion matrix for the polynomial, and by the Abel-Ruffini theorem there is no algebraic solution of 5th order polynomials in general. But here everything is (in principle) a finite algebraic process: taking a QR factorization, getting the eigenvalues of $R$ by looking at the diagonal, then solving the linear equations $Au-\lambda u=0$ to get the eigenvectors of $R$.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Thank you for your reply!